# Wordpress image picker - using in theme options page

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm making my first wordpress theme.
I want to use Wordpress built-in media picker to choose logo image and/or header image. 
How can I make a button to open the picker and save the picked image in theme settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of this tutorial. There is no difference if you use the Media Selector for your theme or for your plugin. http://jeroensormani.com/how-to-include-the-wordpress-media-selector-in-your-plugin/